# How to change the permission for a specific directory without affecting the permission of everything inside that directory?

Tags: linux, chmod

I would like to ONLY change the permission of a specific directory without changing the permission of the files or directories that it contains.
I know that the following command will recursively alter the permission of all dir and files in it:

```
chmod -R 777
```

And the following will change only the files but not the directories that it contains:

```
chmod -r 777
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, so it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chmod 777 /path/to/specific/dir

Comment: just specify without command line options.
if you don't have an alias on chmod, which is unlikely this should work.
alternative try 
\chmod 777 /path/to/specific/dir
to avoid the alias of beeing processed

Comment: would you be able to help me with this issue. it is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128523/cannot-send-email-via-aws-ses-from-https-request?noredirect=1#comment83233778_48128523

Answer (score 0):

The *-r* or *-R* in the Command means that it change the Permission/Owner of all Files and Directory's in the directory!!